# how to run same jquery function to mulitple elements having same class

Tags: jquery

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idsMj.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idsMj.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPUFD.png this is my frontend index page and i have 2 menu having submenu. i used jquery function to get the sub menu but jquery function runs only in the first element.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idsMj.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otlwu.png)

Comment: please post code not pictures of code

Answer (score 0):

Just apply the class selector:

`$(".my-class").someFunction();`